# Drawing tree in latex

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm trying to draw a **tree** using `Tikz`. My code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=0.7cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white!100]
    
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
    
    \node (proA) [process] {{A}};
    \node (proB) [process, right of = proA] {{B}};
    
    \node (pro1) [process, below of = proA] {{1}};
    
    \node (pro2) [process, below of = pro1] {{$S_2$}};
    \node (pro3) [process, right of = pro2] {{$S_3$}};
    
    \node (pro6) [process, below of = pro2] {{6}};
    \node (pro7) [process, right of = pro6] {{7}};
    \node (pro8) [process, right of = pro7] {{8}};
    \node (pro9) [process, right of = pro8] {{9}};
    
    \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
    \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro3);
    
    \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro6);
    \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro7);
    \draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (pro8);
    \draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (pro9);
    
    \draw [arrow] (proA) -- (pro1);
    \draw [arrow] (proB) -- (pro1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:CTU_partitioning}
\end{figure}
```

However, it produces output similar to the right side of the image, when I require output similar to the left side.

[image]

How can I fix this out? There could be **more levels** and **nodes** in the tree. please suggest a **smart way to draw** this type of figure in latex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By use of `forest` package (for tree below node `1`) and Ti*k*Z picture for node above (for start, however there is more sophisticated way to draw complete images with forest):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
%   nodes
    draw, minimum size=2em, inner sep=1pt,
%   tree
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=7mm,
    s sep=7mm
            }
[1, name=s
    [S\textsubscript{2}
        [6]
        [7]
    ]
    [S\textsubscript{3}
        [8]
        [9]    
    ]
]
\node (a)   [draw, minimum size=2em,
             above left=7mm and 7mm of s] {A};
\node (b)   [draw, minimum size=2em,
             above right=7mm and 7mm of s] {B};
\draw (a.south) -- (s.north) -- (b.south);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```